# Make an API call from one container to another

Tags: docker-compose, next.js, server-side-rendering, docker-network

I have a node application , a next.js app for front end ,Redis and Postgres as databases . I have dockerized Next.js and node.js in different containers .
Docker-compose.yaml is as follows

```
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    restart: always
  postgres-server:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports: 
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
        - ./docker/postgres/data/data/pg_hba.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/app_data/pg_hba.conf
        - ./src/db/sql/CREATE_TABLES.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/CREATE_TABLES.sql
        - ./src/db/sql/INSERT_TO_TABLES.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/INSERT_TO_TABLES.sql
        - ./src/db/sql/CREATE_FUNCTIONS.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/CREATE_FUNCTIONS.sql
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "4200:4200" 
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

When using SSR , I cannot make a request to localhost:4200 .Now, I get that it is because they are in different containers and if the request is not from client side , then the client container is being checked for server at port 4200. Now , I am not sure how to simply refer to the container using the container name or something to make an API request for the SSR data (like `fetch('node-app/users')`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

docker-compose sets up a network for all the services in a compose file. To reach another container in the network, you use the name of that container as a hostname, and it will resolve to the right ip.

So in your case doing `fetch('http://node-app:4200/users')` should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah , that did the trick . Cannot believe I spent hours to get it to work and didnt try this.